# SharePoint online - Quick links Target Audience

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, groups, quick-links

I want to use SharePoint (online) group in Target audience for Quick links web part. But I am not able to do so. Only option is to use AD groups.

Is there any other way to map SharePoint group in target audience for Quick links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, **No**. SharePoint groups are not supported in audience targeting in SharePoint online modern experience.

> Azure AD groups (including security groups and Microsoft 365 groups) are supported with the exception of AAD dynamic groups.

**Documentation**: [Target content to a specific audience on a SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/target-content-to-a-specific-audience-on-a-sharepoint-site-68113d1b-be99-4d4c-a61c-73b087f48a81)

> Currently you can only use AD groups or Microsoft 365 groups to target audiences.

**Source**: [Audience Targeting for Quick Links Web Part in SharePoint Online](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/17/audience-targeting-for-quick-links-web-part-in-sharepoint-online/)

---

You can vote on below similar ideas on SharePoint Feedback portal:

1. [Quick Links Audience Targeting to SharePoint Groups](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/e21f5712-d37a-ec11-a81b-6045bd7bf64c)
2. [Allow Site Owners, Site Members, Site Visitors as selectable groups to audience target](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/61bc80db-bf7d-ec11-a81b-0022484f26d4)
3. [Navigation audience targeting support SharePoint groups](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/14b5c73a-de1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8914)

Comment: Thank you Ganesh. I can set the SharePoint groups in audience targeting for Navigation by opening link .../_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx  ( without activating publishing feature ) and that works in SharePoint online. This means that only Quick links web part has the issue in SharePoint online as you have mentioned ....

Comment: Yes, all the modern experience web parts does not support SP groups in audience targeting.

Comment: does that means .../_layouts/15/AreaNavigationSettings.aspx is not the modern experience ?

Comment: Yes, this particular "Navigation Settings" page is in classic experience.